# Set default rules for type using AJV

Tags: validation, jsonschema, ajv

I'm trying to figure out how I can globally say that all arrays must be of length 1 without having to use minItems: 1 every place in the schema I specify an array. I looking at creating a custom type and that is an option but I feel like there should be a better way?

Another global limitation is not allowing any empty strings.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can never change the behavior of a keyword (globally or otherwise).  Your best bet is to create a file that includes your special rules.

`global.js`

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "non-empty-array": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can reference this file any time you want to use those special rules.

`example.js`

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "/global.js#/definitions/non-empty-array" }],
      "items": { "type": "string" }
    },
    "b": {
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "global.js#/definitions/non-empty-array" }],
      "items": { "type": "integer" }
    }
  }
}
```